# healthcheck for the image traefik:1.6

Tags: docker, traefik

How can I build a docker-compose file with the healthcheck for the image traefik:1.6 to validate if the container is healthy? Remarks: The image does not have cmd-shell access. I would not like to change the version of the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [healthcheck command](https://docs.traefik.io/v1.6/basics/#command-healthcheck).

You have to activate the [ping](https://docs.traefik.io/v1.6/configuration/ping/).

After you have to define a [healthcheck section](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#healthcheck) in your docker-compose file.

example:

```
proxy:
  image: traefik:1.6
  command: --api --docker --ping
  ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "8080:8080"
  # ...
  healthcheck:
    test: ["CMD", "traefik" ,"healthcheck"]
    interval: 30s
    timeout: 3s
    retries: 30
```

Comment: I added the ping and added the healthcheck but only get unhealthy status. What can I be doing wrong? I did as follows:

To enable ping:
`command: --api --docker --ping --ping.entryPoint=http://:8080/ping 
ports:
  - "80:80"      # The HTTP port
  - "8080:8080"  # The Web UI (enabled by --api)`
  
To enable healthcheck:
`healthcheck:
  test: ["CMD", "traefik", "healthcheck"]
  interval: 10s
  timeout: 3s
  retries: 3`

Comment: `command: --api --docker --ping` -> ok
`--ping.entryPoint=http://:8080/ping` -> is not good, please remove.

Comment: In my case to work I had to use the image traefik:1.7.6-alpine and add the command --ping also in the healthcheck.

`...
image: traefik:1.7.6-alpine
command: --api --docker --ping
...
healthcheck:
    test: ["CMD", "traefik" ,"healthcheck", "--ping"]
    interval: 3s
    timeout: 3s
    retries: 3`
 
Thank you @ldez.

Answer (score 2):

For traefik version 1.7, the healthcheck command should be `./traefik healthcheck --ping`. I [found it](https://community.traefik.io/t/how-to-do-healthcheck-on-traefik-itself/1462/5) after a long struggle period with traefik parameters.

Hope it helps somebody.

```
image: traefik:1.7
command:
  - "--docker"
  - "--docker.swarmmode"
  - "--docker.watch"
  - "--ping"
  - "--loglevel=INFO"
healthcheck:
  test: ["CMD", "./traefik", "healthcheck", "--ping"]
  interval: 30s
  timeout: 3s
  retries: 30
```

Comment: Thanks I was loking for it recently, and found out I actually answered it on the forums :)

Comment: Great @ArchimedesTrajano! Thanks for sharing the answer in the first place

Answer (score 1):

For traefik v^2.0, You just have to enable the `ping` command and define the `healthcheck` attribute and its required children.

```
traefik:
  image: traefik:2.7
  command: 
    - --ping=true
    # ...
  ports:
    - target: 80
      published: 80
      protocol: tcp
      mode: host
    - target: 443
      published: 443
      protocol: tcp
      mode: host
    # ...
  healthcheck:
    test: ["CMD", "traefik", "healthcheck", "--ping"]
    interval: 5s
    retries: 3
```